# How do you connect to the internet with Ubuntu server 20.04 without wireless tools?

Tags: server, 20.04, internet

I completed the setup of Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS and skipped the step where you set up an internet connection. I am also unable to download the wireless tools package, which makes me unable to use things like iwconfig and ifconfig, which other threads tell me to use. Is there any other way to connect to the internet without the use of these packages?

Comment: If you can't use a wired connection either, it is possible to use another computer that does have Internet connection, download the packages there, and transfer them to your system using a USB stick.

Comment: Is this easier if I do it wired? Also, does it matter if I'm connecting to Ethernet through a usb to Ethernet adapter?

Comment: Of course it will be easier. The Internet connection will be automatically detected and you will be able to install and update packages. A USB adapter will function like any other network card.